# oh-my-zsh: ignore untracked files

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Are there any options/flags/settings for `oh-my-zsh` that would make it ignore untracked files by default when setting the prompt?

Many of my repos contain untracked files, this causes the prompt to have the little asterisk after the branch name even when there are no modified files:

```
matt@khea /tmp/dotfiles [master *]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through the `oh-my-zsh` I would think the `$DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY` should help a bit there: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/git.zsh#L20

Strangely enough, since it appears to call `git status` anyhow, I would expect it to work by default. Are you running the latest version?

Comment: Latest version I believe.   Anyways, It worked!  I had come across this option at some point, but I didn't know which value to set it to.  I had set it to ```1``` (instead of ```true```), and maybe got distracted or something, but went looking elsewhere.  Thanks!